# How I can remove build in app from an Android device using adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, uninstallation

I'm trying to remove app from app list on my phone, the application always send popup advertising for provider of my sim card, the application exists on application manager but i can't remove it using manual method, i'm trying to remove it using adb shell.

Here’s a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the app]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear

Comment: i dont know what the package name of this application

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
adb shell pm uninstall app.to.remove
```

or, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear)

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:app.to.remove
```

please refer to [adb manual](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) for further options. you should find the package name in the application manager.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't know the package name of app.

Comment: you should find it in the application manager, where you were trying to uninstall that app

Comment: the application appears on application manager like this [link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5A8DxeueoOOOEZOR0J6Qnl6VEdlVnJOMlYtVDBlM2N5QlhJ&authuser=0

Comment: look in the running app list, there you should find it (if it is running)
sorry, before i couldn't see the screenshot. Maybe you can try also with this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectsexception.myapplist&hl=it