# Uninstall apk Using Asus Zenfone 2

Tags: android, uninstallation

I created an Android application then installed the apk on my ASUS Zenfone 2. When I tried to uninstall it, the logo of my application is shown (full screen) but the application was not removed/uninstalled. The confirmation message is not even displayed. I tried to install/uninstall my application on other phone and it worked. What seems to be the problem with Zenfone 2?

Comment: Try using [ADB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear)

Comment: I tried uninstalling apk using adb shell with the following commands from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear):

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE -d "package:PACKAGE"
adb shell am start -n com.android.packageinstaller/.UninstallerActivity -d "package:PACKAGE"
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d "package:PACKAGE". The result is the same.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @user123456  no solution yet?